# Laravel uses 100 times more memory than the native php

Tags: laravel, memory, nginx, fastcgi

Nginx + PHP FasCGI on mint linux.

I tested the table writing in csv on Laravel.
Laravel uses 100 times more memory than the native php.

Laravel use eloquent. As far as I understand mysqli is used.
Native php clean mysqli.

Just table ( no relationship, int and float) 9000 records Laravel take ~65 MB to retrun.
Native PHP ~ 300 KB.

If for one `foreach` take 10000 records, server out of memory (128MB by default).

Even in model first row return data more then 5 times longer then second line.

```
return self::take( $take )->skip( $skip )->get(); // 9000 ~ 5-6 sec.

return DB::table('sales')->take( $take )->skip( $skip )->get(); // 9000 <1 sec.
```

**Anyone can tell why so much difference?**

At high loads, it will be able to run (Laravel)?

Comment: The first row (`self::take`) will run slower than the second row (`DB::table`) because the first row will return a Collection of Model objects, while the second one will return an array of `stdClass` objects, and models being more complex take more time to set up and consume more memory, so it makes perfect sense. As for why the difference in memory usage is so high, please post the _"Native php clean mysqli"_ script that you're comparing this to, because the memory usage  discrepancy should be very small between your `mysqli` script and the second `DB::table` statement.

Comment: Additionally, Laravel uses PDO, not mysqli.

Comment: You might want to check out the following section in the docs: **Chunking Results From A Table** https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries